# onDrop event not fired in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I want to drag from a image to a span like this:

DRAG FROM HERE

```
<img src={img_src} draggable='true' onDragStart={this.dragStartHandler(idx)}/>
```

DROP HERE:

```
<span onDragOver={this.preventDefault} onDrop={this.dropHandler} 
    onClick={this.handleClick}>DROP HERE</span>
```

DRAG AND DROP HANDLERS:

```
  dragStartHandler = (idx) => (event) => {
    console.log(idx,"called drag event and loaded data in drag object")
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', idx); 
  }

  dropHandler = () => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("DROP EVENT")
  }

  preventDefault = () => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("prevent default")
  }
```

A fiddle with this code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/229855/

But the drop event is never called when i click on the draggable image, drag it over the drop area and release the mouse button. This is on chrome, firefox and safari.

How can I call the drop event correctly?

Comment: can you do this in fiddler?

Comment: yes, i added a fiddle to my question. any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So I took a look at a program that I implemented a while ago with `React` and using drag and drop. I ended up creating a file and implementing everything for DnD in pure `JS`. I just called the script and attached all the events in `ComponentDidMount` to the DOM elements. I can't seem to figure out why it's not working, maybe something subtle we missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

Change

```
onDragOver={this.preventDefault}
```

to

```
onDragOver={this.preventDefault()}
```

if you're on ES6. Never harmful to go back to the basics :-)

Comment: The same worked for FC as well. e.g. `onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}`.